# Haproxy logging doesn't work. Does that have anything to do with csf?

Tags: firewall, haproxy, rsyslog, csf

Does `Haproxy` log every time a connection is made? I have followed instructions from other threads to set up logging via `rsyslogd`. Even though the files are created (haproxy.log,haproxy-info.log and haproxy-allbutinfo.log), no logs have been written into any of them.

I have checked the lfg.log, and these may shed some light on the problem:

```
Sep 12 22:50:44 : *Suspicious Process* PID:17551 PPID:17551 User:haproxy Uptime:62 secs EXE:/usr/sbin/haproxy CMD:/usr/sbin/haproxy -D -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid
Sep 12 22:50:44 : *Suspicious Process* PID:17552 PPID:17552 User:haproxy Uptime:62 secs EXE:/usr/sbin/haproxy CMD:/usr/sbin/haproxy -D -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid
```

The `RESTRICT_SYSLOG` is set to 3 in csf config. I have also added `haproxy` as an allowed user for rsyslogd in `/etc/csf/csf.syslogusers` but still no logs have been written. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the following setup?

csf config

```
RESTRICT_SYSLOG = "3"

# Allow incoming UDP ports
UDP_IN = "20,21,53,514"

# Allow outgoing UDP ports
# To allow outgoing traceroute add 33434:33523 to this list 
UDP_OUT = "20,21,53,514"
```

/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

```
global
   log 127.0.0.1   local2       
   maxconn 2048             
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
```

/etc/rsyslog.d/haproxy.conf

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
$UDPServerRun 514    
local2.*    /var/log/haproxy.log
local2.=info     /var/log/haproxy-info.log
local2.notice    /var/log/haproxy-allbutinfo.log
```

"haproxy" user added to /etc/csf/csf.syslogusers

```
  # Other users:
  haproxy
```

Updated: I just disabled csf and tried again. Still haproxy doesn't write anything into the files.

Comment: Have you tried it with CSF/LDF disabled?

Comment: @GregL Yes, I have tried it without CSF, but the log still doesn't work

Comment: What's the value of `RESTRICT_SYSLOG_GROUP`?

Comment: @GregL, Default Value: `RESTRICT_SYSLOG_GROUP = "mysyslog"` `RESTRICT_SYSLOG = "3"`

Comment: According to [this](http://configserver.com/cp/csfdemo/config.html), having `RESTRICT_SYSLOG` set to '3', restricts syslog/rsyslog access to `RESTRICT_SYSLOG_GROUP`. Maybe try changing `RESTRICT_SYSLOG` to '2' and see if it works.

Comment: @GregL I have tried it with no success. I'm starting to think the firewall isn't the reason for the problem. I have disabled csf for a while but still nothing written in the haproxy log file.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to get logs written into the file. 
Besides adding the log setting to the global section, I should have added a reference in the default section as well. To quote from this [tutorial](http://kvz.io/blog/2010/08/11/haproxy-logging/) which is the only piece I have found mentions this important setting:

> In your backends or default config, refer to global:

```
   defaults
        log             global
```

My settings in /etc/rsyslog/haproxy.conf

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1

local1.* -/var/log/haproxy_1.log
& ~
```

It turns out there is nothing to do with `csf`. I have closed the UDP and the logging still works

Comment: Thanks ! I missed that ! the "defaults" section. I went down to logrotate or iptables to see if my UDP traffic was blocked somewhere, or if rotation caused deletion of logs, I was so mad to see this file created, but not filled ^^ +1

Answer (score -2):

For `haproxy.cfg` please modify the log level.

```
log             127.0.0.1       local3 info
```

You can configure the log level (emerg alert crit err warning). You can use one or if you need to use multiple you can simply defined giving spaces.

```
log             127.0.0.1       local3 info warning
```

For rsyslog:

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
```

Include this rule before your debug rule. Otherwise you will see the Haproxy logs in syslogs.

```
if $programname startswith 'haproxy' then  
  /var/log/haproxy.log & ~
```

Comment: `You can use one or if you need to use multiple you can simply defined giving spaces.` Actually, that's not what specifying two levels does. The [docs](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-log) say that `By default, all messages are sent. If a level is specified, only messages with a severity at least as important as this level will be sent. An optional minimum level can be specified. If it is set, logs emitted with a more severe level than this one will be capped to this level.`

Comment: @user312067, I have followed your instructions, but yet no logs have been written.